# Reload multi webcam(jpg) IMG with jquery

Tags: jquery

Just stated to play around with Jquery and Java. I stated to setup a page with sevral webcams and updating the live preview image using Jquery. Tryed to google around but I'm not able to find an "easy" solution for reloading sevral camera jpegs without reloading the complete page.
So far I came up with this and it's "working"

**Script part**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval('updateCamera()',2000);
});

function updateCamera() {
        $('#camera1').attr('src','camera1.jpg?' + Math.random());
        $('#camera2').attr('src','camera2.jpg?' + Math.random());
        }
```

**HTML**

```
<img id="camera1" src="camera1.jpg" border=1/>
<img id="camera2" src="camera2.jpg" border=1/>
```

Anyone who got an better idea / solution for doing this? Like just updating the id element?
Sorry if the question is abit "newbie" but there got to be an easier solution for this.

Comment: I really don't see anything wrong with this approach, this is actually how I would handle it as well.  My only suggestion would be to use `new Date().getTime()` instead of `Math.random()`, but in practice it won't really make a difference.

Comment: Yep, I guess it's better with getTime if it updates alot of times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a good, simple solution and if it works, just stick with it. You can make it a bit more dynamic if you wish:

```
function updateCamera() {
    $('.cameras').each(function() {
        var url = $(this).attr('src').split('?')[0];
        $(this).attr('src', url + '?' + Math.random());
    })
}
```

This way you don't need to specify each of your images separately if you just give them the same classname.

Comment: I believe using `this.src` would suffice, so you don't create two new jQuery object in the process

Comment: Thank you Tatu. Just what I was looking for. @Yi Juang. I'll try and play around alittle with it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another variation based on Tatu's answer that I just finished using on my own site. It allows me to pass other required arguments to the webcam. It also uses timestamps instead of a random number. That just feels slightly cleaner.

Modify your original image URLs to end with "&t=", and make sure your image tags belong to the class 'cameras'.

```
<img class="cameras" src="http://kitchen/snapshot.cgi?user=guest&pwd=&t=">


<script type="text/javascript">    

  function updateCamera() {
    time = new Date().getTime();
    $('.cameras').each(function() {
      var url = $(this).attr('src').replace(/&t=\d*/, '&s='+time);
      $(this).attr('src', url);
    })
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval('updateCamera()', 2000);
  });

</script>
```